# How to print out a sheet of images from a folder of images

Tags: macos, microsoft-word, images

I have a folder full of individual JPEG images on Mac OS X. I want to print it out on a sheet, so that they are side to side. I also have Microsoft Word 2004, if that helps.

Comment: i know how to do that on windows.... not mac...

Comment: Going to need more information. Do you want them scaled, tiles to fit as many as possible, etc

Comment: @soandos I want them to be touching, fill the page, and stay at their current size.

Comment: And if this is impossible (due to resolution issues)?

Comment: @soandos Then resize them a bit? They are playing cards, so I doubt that will be a problem.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you can use the script in [this post](https://www.velvetcache.org/2009/03/30/imagemagick-thumbnails-and-contact-sheets), which explains how to create a [proof sheet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contact_print) with Imagemagick, which is [available for OS X](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/download.php#macosx).